# Trapped in Windows

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, filevault

A similar question has been asked here: [Bootcamp stuck in Windows](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142486/bootcamp-stuck-in-windows), but mine is a little different - the answer did not work for me.

I have a MacBook Pro 13,2 that is running 10.13.1 and has a Boot Camp install of Windows 10, Fall Creator's Update. (don't know version number atm)

Switching to Windows is easy. Hold option while I boot, enter the firmware password, and I can select the Windows partition. However getting out of Windows is not easy.

I have the Boot Camp toolbar menu visible on Windows, but whenever I press Restart in macOS, it tells me that the macOS volume cannot be found.

To get out of Windows earlier when I had this problem, I would reboot into *Windows Recovery*, which takes no time at all then press turn off the computer. My Mac would reboot into macOS just fine.

Now, the only way that I can find out of Windows is to reboot into *macOS recovery*, which takes a few minutes to load.

**Why can't I use the Boot Camp toolbar menu to return to macOS? How do I repair that?**

---

Some notes about my system:

- FileVault is on
- Firmware password is on
- BitLocker for Windows is off
- An NVRAM reset does not work while in Windows
- Boot Camp utility in Windows does not show any volumes other than the Windows volume
- macOS partition is in APFS
- macOS version 10.13.1 (17B1003)

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of your problem is use of APFS. The Boot Camp software installed in Window probably can not recognize this format.

Possible solutions or work arounds are listed below.

- Don't use APFS. Revert back to a legacy JHFS+ or Core Storage partition for macOS.
- Run the Apple Update software under Windows to see if a Boot Camp update has been released.
- Hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key immediately after starting or restarting your Mac. Release the <kbd>option</kbd> key when the Startup Manager appears. Select the macOs operating system to boot from. Note: If you hold down the <kbd>control</kbd> while making your selection, then your choice will become the default.

Answer (score 0):

Restart from Windows (Bootcamp) and press the **Option** key - and not Command, it took me a while too.